# Why a Jenkins job takes longer time to run between farms?

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins

I am using a jenkins configuration where the same job is being executed in different locations: one in farm1 and another in an overseas farm2. 
The Jenkins master server is located in farm1.

I encounter a situation where the job on farm2 takes much more time to finish, sometimes twice the elapsed time. 
Do you have an idea what could be the reason for that? 
is there a continuous master-slave discussion during the build that can cause such delay?

The job is a maven junit test + ui seleniun using vnc server on the slave

Thanks in advance,
Roy

Answer (score 3):

I assume your server farms have identical hardware specs?

Network differences while checking out code, downloading dependencies, etc. Workspace of Master and Slave are on different servers

If you are archiving artifacts, they are usually archived back on Master, even when the job is run on Slave.

Install [**Timestamper**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Timestamper) plugin, enable it, and then review the logs of both the Master and the Slave runs, and see where there is a big time difference (you can configure Timestamper to show time as increments from the start of job, this would be helpful here)